# PHP to INSERT new Row to DB with 1 variable and all others default?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a DB with about 10 columns. I want to be able to have a form that inputs the first column's variable, and use the pre-defined default on the remainder.

Here is my current form on **locationbuilder.php**:

```
<form method="post" action="builder.php" id="locationbuld">
    Location Name <input type="text" name="locationname"/><br/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

**builder.php**

```
$propertyname = $_POST['locationname'];
$loadCP = $conn->query("INSERT INTO properties (propertyName) VALUES ('$propertyname')");
header("Location: locationbuilder.php");
```

When I run the form, it goes through and redirects back just fine, but it doesn't insert the new row. I'm assuming it's because I have about 9 undetermined columns, but I'm not 100% sure how to remedy this.

Thanks!

---

Also, in case it helps, here is my create table I used so you can see the data/columns:

```
$cp = "CREATE TABLE properties (
    id INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    propertyName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    location VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT 'South Side',
    propertyType VARCHAR(8) DEFAULT 'Business',
    businessType VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'None',
    ownerName VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT 'None',
    gangHQFor VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT 'None',
    drugFront VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT 'No',
    productionType VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'None',
    productionQuantity INT(4) DEFAULT '0',
    weeklyCost INT(15) DEFAULT '0',
    dailyIncome INT(15) DEFAULT '0',
    available VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT 'Yes',
    confiscated VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT 'No',
    confiscatedTime VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '0'
)";
$conn->query($cp);
```

Comment: Just remove not null

Comment: I destroyed the table, removed NOT NULL, re-built the table, and tried again - still no INSERT

Comment: @bader it did not work. It is still not INSERTING even without the `NOT NULL`

Comment: Because your primary key is propertyname

Comment: You want to add another column call it Id for example and make it autoincreasing and give it primary key

Comment: You can do it like. first try to check that  any record exist with given value or not if yes then update query otherwise insert query. also rest of your field must have null acceptance at table side. means if no value given automatically it will field with  null value.

Comment: but the best is make an id field which is primary key and auto-incremented int value.

Comment: @bader adding the `id` column as `PRIMARY KEY` did not work either - updated table above

Comment: VARCHAR will work as a primary key as long as it's unique (I think auto increment INT is better, but technically either should work).  The NOT NULL is also acceptable as long as there's also a DEFAULT (not null without an explicit default will fail, however).  Try checking the error property after your insert statement?

Comment: In that case go to phpmyadmin and test your sql output

Comment: @bader worked perfectly in phpmyadmin - still not via the `php`

Comment: @jpgerb please check my solution. try it. it will help you to find out actually what problems occur at php side.

Comment: Moving this up here (re: escaping).  You have no idea what the client might send you as the value for "locationname" - they could send you quotes, other SQL symbols, etc. to break your database, get info they're not supposed to, and so on.  Escaping is basically sanitizing those values, so if they send you a single quote for example, you interpret it as part of the value and NOT part of the structure of the SQL command.  There are built in escaping functions depending on what API you're using (mysql_real_escape_string for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how's you are creating your connection object `$conn`. So i gave this code, try this and tell:-

Your table must be like this:-

```
TABLE properties(some default values are changed) =
    id INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    propertyName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    location VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT 'South Side',
    propertyType VARCHAR(8) DEFAULT 'Business',
    businessType VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'None',
    ownerName VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT 'NULL',
    gangHQFor VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT 'NULL',
    drugFront VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT 'No',
    productionType VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'NULL',
    productionQuantity INT(4) DEFAULT '0',
    weeklyCost INT(15) DEFAULT '0',
    dailyIncome INT(15) DEFAULT '0',
    available VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT 'Yes',
    confiscated VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT 'No',
    confiscatedTime VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '0'
```

And code :-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$conn = mysqli_connect('host name','user name','password','database name') or die(mysqli_connect_error());

$propertyname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['locationname']);

$loadCP = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO properties (propertyName) VALUES ('$propertyname')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
if($loadCP){
header("Location: locationbuilder.php");    
}else{
    echo "some error occur.Please try again";
}
?>
```

Note:- change credentials value and other variables value accordingly. Thanks

Comment: worked with 1 small edit - just needed the single quotes around $propertyname in the query... not 100% what exactly allowed it to work, but I'm going to compare - BTW - the $conn is in an include and i'm still using it - wasn't the issue

Comment: I don't get what you are asking?  by the way thanks for marking and upvote. glad to help you.

Comment: @anat kumar singh - I wasn't asking anything - that worked - thank you!

Comment: My pleasure. :):):):).have fun.

Answer (score 0):

**builder.php**

```
<?php
$propertyname = $_POST['locationname'];
$loadCP = $conn->query("INSERT INTO properties (propertyName) VALUES ('$propertyname')");
header("Location: locationbuilder.php");
?>
```

Comment: you should remove single quotes from variable inside query

Comment: Already tried this originally - doesn't work. Also strings need to be surrounded by single quotes

Comment: try this ".$propertyname."

Answer (score -1):

There are quite a number of things that could have gone wrong since we don't have a copy of your full application, however these would help

1. Check your connection string, are you using a mysql abstraction class ?
2. Use a debugger to log your errors, despite the fact that the script ran did not mean it didn't generate an error. Depending on your error setting, it might have failed silently. Firephp might be an easy to learn PHP debugging tool